# Changed iCloud password but Yosemite password not changed

Tags: macos, icloud, password

I recently changed my iCloud password on my iPhone but the password to log in to my Macbook Pro (running Yosemite) hasn't changed. When I click change password it says that my account is using my iCloud password.

How do I get my Mac to update the password it is using?

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings User and groups, then click Change password... and click use iCloud password or, simply Reconfigure the password